# Coldfusion(cdata): What can be an alternative to CDATA to work with firefox too?

Tags: xml, firefox, browser, coldfusion

I have a table of data and links created dynamically. The website was built with coldfusion that I don't know much about.
The line of code that populates the data to the page is the following (I'm sure about this at least):

```
<cfoutput>
       <td>
     <![CDATA[
    <a href="##" onclick="javascript:viewRecord('#priKeyId#');setTimeout('gridMenu.cancelmenu();',50);" title="View"> #rowdat#
        </a>
           ]]>
      </td>
   </cfoutput>
```

The trick seems in the CDATA tag because if I don't use it and switch the code back to xmlformat(#rowdat#) instead; firefox likes it and it shows me all data/links in table without issues!.. HOWEVER, the problem moves to the rest of the browsers! (chrome, IE, safari they all like the cdata!)
Any help how to get firefox to show the table data correctly?

Thanks

Update1: this is a [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwpc8UOGMwadbmp4dUJ4NmFYYzA/edit?usp=sharing) that has a picture that maybe can explain the issue better than me!

Update2: It seems that the issue is with the link generated from the href="##". So I tried to set the actual link before the code AND HTMLEditFormat() it like the following:

```
 <cfset mylink ="https://my.site.com/index.cfm?event=public.my.site.view&site_id=" & priKeyId 
 <cfset mylink = HTMLEditFormat(mylink)>
 <cfif colName eq link>

 <cfoutput>
  <td id="cdata">
  <a onclick="viewRecord('#priKeyId#');setTimeout('gridMenu.cancelmenu();', 50);return false;" href="#mylink#"  title="View">#rowdat#</a>
  </td>
   </cfoutput>
```

However, that didn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks to you @iKnowKungFu and @TechMark2K for your inputs that helped me discover/eliminate options to solve my issue.

Second, knowing how FF behaves towards CDATA sections is essential to know how to workaround it. I found out that FF comments out from the beginning of CDATA all the way till the end of next HTML tag and stops right there! Also, it interprets any none-Javascript dynamically generated code literally(e.g. link generated from href="##").

Knowing that, I solved my issue in 5 steps :

1- Use CDATA section since it fixes the problem in all browsers except firefox and deal with  Firefox's problem separately.
2- Make Firefox show the content of CDATA section properly:

```
 a- Comment out (not removing) only the closing of CDATA tag: `<!-- ]]> -->` (FF kept showing it at the end of my text). Other browsers' behavior towards cdata didn't change with this modification.
 b- Ditch the href="## as FF doesn't interpret it well inside CDATA. So I generated it outside CDATA and used a variable instead: href=#myLink# .
```

3- Send the link(or array of links) into a javascript variable using CF function #toScript(#linksArray#,"links")#. If you use an array, make sure to send distinguishing IDs with the links too (personally I didn't need to do this step bec of the plugin functionality, so I skipped it even after working on it!)
4- give intended text an id = "myText" (not for the whole tag that includes them, use `<span id ="myText"`> )

```
5- if (you skipped step 3, for any reason, like me) {  
      style "myText" id to look/behave like a link!(and don't tell others about it)  
        } else { 
            or better, using JavaScript or jQuery, surround "myText" id text contents with an anchor tag of the matching link from the javascript variable(or array): "links" .
}
```

Till FF development community wake up and just fix this bug in FireFox(not a fan luckily) I hope this will help someone out there who stumbles upon CDATA-Firefox related problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than close this, let me point you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179563/cdata-not-parsing-properly-in-firefox), which states that Firefox doesn't support "disable-output-escaping".

If you're on ColdFusion 10,

`<a href="##" onclick="javascript:viewRecord('#priKeyId#');setTimeout('gridMenu.cancelmenu();',50);" title="View">#encodeForHTML(rowdat)#</a>`

otherwise, xmlFormat() is fine.

Comment: thanks for the response. xmlFormat() works but only on FF! And thats what I'm trying to find a fix for. I tried encodeFORHTML() and it didn't work. It gave me on FF the following message: ** No matching Method/Function for ENCODEFORHTML(numeric).(I think the server's Coldfusion is 7 version) any alternatives??

Comment: Just use HTMLEditFormat(). EncodeForHTML() only works out of the box with CF 10+.

Comment: I tried HTMLEditFormat() too. It works only on FF ! all other browsers show no links at all or "null"s instead in IE case

Comment: Update your question to show a sample of the content in "rowdat". The encoding is probably escaping too many characters in that string. You might just need to output it without any CDATA or encoding.

Comment: I think now the main issue is with the href="##" part. It seems that IE parses as an undefined reference and thats why it's showing it as "null". Any workarounds for this please?

Comment: If you have <cfoutput>##</cfoutput>, then it outputs a single "#". If you don't have that section of code wrapped in CFOUTPUT, then just use a single "#".

Comment: can you please elaborate on your <cfoutput>##</cfoutput> comment? As you can see, the <td> tag is already surrounded with <cfoutput></cfoutput>. Do you mean to add another <cfoutput></cfoutput> around the ##? I tried to use one single # before and it crashes the link on all browsers(with and without cdata).

Comment: Don't worry about that comment. <cfoutput>##</cfoutput> renders a single "#", but that is already occurring. Is this a standard HTML table or is this HTML that's being converted to some JavaScript grid? If it's plain HTML, look at the rendered HTML source code from the browser. Maybe that can give you an idea of why the text of the link is being displayed, but the link itself is not.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's being converted to a JavaScript grid. Using some very old plugin (Rico LiveGrid) in addition to the old Coldfusion MVC framework (model-glue). But I found a workaround for this issue. It's in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Remove CDATA, don't use it, instead use this:

```
<cfoutput>
    <td>     
        <a href="##" onclick="javascript:viewRecord('#priKeyId#');setTimeout('gridMenu.cancelmenu();',50);" title="View">#HTMLEditFormat(rowdat)#</a>           
    </td>
</cfoutput>
```

I've tried in Firefox, IE, Chrome and Opera because HTMLEditFormat() should work. Let me know if it works on yours.

Comment: I already tried that before and it didn't work! (again, only on FF). But I tried it one more time and it still giving me the same result. (maybe you are using it with a code that doesn't have special characters??)

Comment: I'm using it with the string "foo bar" for rowdat. Can you post an example of one of your strings that have special chars, maybe a picture of the string that contains special characters?

Comment: When I just showed the #rowdat# string by itself it worked no problem. But when I put it inside the <a> tag I start getting issues. Which is why I noted above that I think the problem actually is in the link (whether generated using "##" or statically used through #mylink#, pls see Update2 in the question)

Comment: I still think you should go with this 'cfoutput>
    <td>     
        <a href="##" onclick="javascript:viewRecord('#priKeyId#');setTimeout('gridMenu.cancelmenu();',50);" title="View">#HTMLEditFormat(rowdat)#</a>           
    </td>
</cfoutput>' and work out any issues you're getting I suppose in viewRecord() because you might have to html decode references to the anchor in your viewRecord() javascript

Comment: I also tried that before(td inside cfoutput). The problem with this way is that it shows plain text instead of links on all browsers! The viewRecord() is a function within a an old Coldfusion plugin. It's much easier (to me as a non-CF developer) to rebuild the page using HTML-Php-JS than editing a Coldfusion plugin embedded in a model-glue framework!

Comment: I'm glad you've found a solution. All the best.